# Excel VBA : week numbers

Tags: excel, week-number, vba

I'm using Excel VBA, How can I ?

- Input month and year and return all week numbers for this month.
- Input a date and get the week number for this date.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### To get week from Date

> Input a date and get the week number for this date.

#### Code

```
Sub WeekDate()
    Dim InputDate As Date
    Dim week As Long

    InputDate = Now 'Change to desired date/cell
    week = Application.WorksheetFunction.WeekNum(InputDate)
    Debug.Print week
End Sub
```

#### Result

[image: Result1]

### To get all weeks on month

> Input month and year and return all week numbers for this month.

#### Code

```
Sub WeeksInMonth()
    Dim MonthYear As String, txt As String
    Dim InputDate As Date, MonthYearDay As Date
    Dim i As Long, intDaysInMonth As Long, j As Long
    Dim MyArray As Variant
    Dim arr As New Collection, a
    ReDim MyArray(0 To 31)
    j = 0
    InputDate = Now
    MonthYear = Month(InputDate) & "/" & Year(InputDate)
    intDaysInMonth = Day(DateSerial(Year(MonthYear), Month(MonthYear) + 1, 0))
    For i = 1 To intDaysInMonth
        MonthYearDay = DateSerial(Year(InputDate), Month(InputDate), i)
        MyArray(j) = Application.WorksheetFunction.WeekNum(MonthYearDay)
        j = j + 1
    Next i

    ReDim Preserve MyArray(0 To j - 1)
    On Error Resume Next
    For Each a In MyArray
        arr.Add a, CStr(a)
    Next

    For i = 1 To arr.Count
        Debug.Print arr(i)
    Next
End Sub
```

#### Result

[image: Result2]

#### Explanation

- The code first get all the days on a month with `intDaysInMonth`, so on February of 2017 it will output `28`.
- Loop on each day of the month with `MonthYearDay` and populate the array `MyArray` with the week of that day `Application.WorksheetFunction.WeekNum(MonthYearDay)`.
- Then create the collection `arr(i)` to output the unique values from the array `MyArray`

> On future requests, post  what you have tried. I am answering it because i couldn't find a suitable answer for: Input month and year and return all week numbers for this month.

Comment: Thank you sir, I'm not familiar to Stackoverflow guidelines. I will definitely consider what you said.

Comment: @MohammedZegui Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), read [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Please verify [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236).

Comment: Well I get the following error for the second code :
Runtime Error 5 : Invalid procedure call or argument. When I click debug it highlights the following line : 

MyArray(j) = Application.WorksheetFunction.WeekNum(MonthYearDay)

Comment: Are you declaring everything? And are you sure that the Date is inputed as Date?