# How to get the Mondays (full date) in the current month?

Tags: excel, vba, date, calculated-field

I am trying to get all the dates for the Mondays in the current month. For example, in the current month May 2021 we would have: 3/05/2021, 10/05/2021, 17/05/2021, 24/05/2021, 31/05/2021.

On investigation I found this answer for an older question which helps to
[Calculate the number of weeks in a month](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47393516/14106263), however this shows 6 as an answer. Which is correct (See shared calendar). However I wish to count only the Mondays on the month.

[image]

I also have a complementary code which gives me the number of Mondays in the month:

```vb
Sub NumMondays()

    Dim i As Integer
    Dim num_mondays As Integer
    Dim test_date As Date
    Dim orig_month As Integer
    
    month_name = Format(Date, "mmmm")
    year_name = Format(Date, "yyyy")
    ' Get the first day of the month.
    test_date = CDate(month_name & " 1, " & year_name)
    
    ' Count the Mondays.
    orig_month = Month(test_date)
    Do
        num_mondays = num_mondays + 1
        test_date = DateAdd("ww", 1, test_date)
    Loop While (Month(test_date) = orig_month)
    
    Debug.Print test_date
    Debug.Print orig_month
    Debug.Print num_mondays
    
End Sub
```

Such code prints 5 for number of Mondays, however I have been unable to convert this to the actual dates of such Mondays. Any suggestions?

Thanks a lot in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the next code, please:

```
Sub NumMondays()
 Dim i As Long, month_name, year_name, num_mondays As Integer
 Dim test_date As Date, orig_month As Integer, arrMondays, k As Long

 month_name = Format(Date, "mmmm")
 year_name = Format(Date, "yyyy")
 ' Get the first day of the month.
 test_date = CDate(month_name & " 1, " & year_name)

 orig_month = month(test_date)
 ReDim arrMondays(4)
 'extract and count Mondays:
 Do
    If Weekday(test_date, vbMonday) = 1 Then
        arrMondays(k) = test_date: k = k + 1: num_mondays = num_mondays + 1
    End If
    test_date = test_date + 1
 Loop While (month(test_date) = orig_month)
 ReDim Preserve arrMondays(k - 1)

 Debug.Print "Current month no = " & orig_month
 Debug.Print "No of Mondays = " & num_mondays
 Debug.Print Join(arrMondays, ", ")
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks a lot FaneDuru! Your code works just as expected!

Answer (score 3):

### A Functional Solution

A good approach is to use a function that will return a collection of the days from a specified month.

This is similar to other approaches provided — however, this adds a bit of performance and more importantly **intellisense** for the day of the week.

```vb
Public Function GetMonthDays(dayToGet As VbDayOfWeek _
, monthToGetFrom As Long _
, yearToGetFrom As Long) As Collection

    Set GetMonthDays = New Collection
    
    ' First Starting date, and will be used
    ' for incrementing to next date/next day.
    Dim nextDate    As Date
    nextDate = DateSerial(yearToGetFrom, monthToGetFrom, 1)
    
    ' Loop until month changes to next month.
    Do While month(nextDate) = monthToGetFrom
        ' If weekday matches, then add and
        ' increment to next week (7 days)
        If Weekday(nextDate) = dayToGet Then
            GetMonthDays.Add nextDate
            nextDate = nextDate + 7
            
            ' Day did not match, therefore increment
            ' 1 day until it does match.
        Else
            nextDate = nextDate + 1
        End If
    Loop
End Function
```

### Example

Here is a basic example of how to use it.

```vb
Sub testGetMonthDays()
    Dim mondayDate As Variant
    For Each mondayDate In GetMonthDays(vbMonday, month(Date), year(Date))
        Debug.Print mondayDate
    Next
End Sub
```

```
5/3/2021 
5/10/2021 
5/17/2021 
5/24/2021 
5/31/2021
```

Answer (score 1):

Brute force approach

```vb
Sub tester()
    Dim dt
    For Each dt In GetDayDates(2021, 5, "Mon")
        Debug.Print dt
    Next dt
End Sub

Function GetDayDates(yr As Long, mon As Long, d As String)
    Dim dt As Date, col As New Collection
    dt = DateSerial(yr, mon, 1)
    Do While Month(dt) = mon
        If Format(dt, "ddd") = d Then col.Add dt
        dt = dt + 1
    Loop
    Set GetDayDates = col
End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

Different approach. There is a somewhat known Excel formula that provides the Monday of a Given Weeknumber and Year (=DATE(A2, 1, -2) - WEEKDAY(DATE(A2, 1, 3)) + B2 * 7) [A2 is the Year, B2 is the Weeknumber]. In this case I loop all weeks on a month and use that formula on each week.

```
Sub CaseOfTheMondays()
    Dim inDate As Date, sDate As Date, eDate As Date, sYear As Date, mDate As Date
    Dim cMonth As Integer, i As Integer, x As Integer
    inDate = InputBox("Enter a valid date")
    If IsDate(inDate) Then
        ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1).Columns("A").ClearContents
        sDate = DateAdd("d", -(Format(inDate, "d") - 1), inDate)
        eDate = DateAdd("m", 1, inDate) - (Format(inDate, "d") + 1)
        sYear = DateAdd("m", -(Format(inDate, "m") - 1), DateAdd("d", -(Format(inDate, "d") - 1), inDate))
        cMonth = Format(inDate, "m")
        sWeek = WorksheetFunction.WeekNum(sDate, vbMonday)
        eWeek = WorksheetFunction.WeekNum(eDate, vbMonday)
        x = 1
        For i = sWeek To eWeek
            mDate = DateAdd("d", -3, sYear) - Weekday(DateAdd("d", 2, sYear)) + (i * 7)
            If Format(mDate, "m") = cMonth Then
                ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1).Cells(x, 1).Value = mDate
                x = x + 1
            End If
        Next i
    Else
        MsgBox "invalid date"
    End If
End Sub
```